# how to render multiple control types in dataGridViewComboBoxCell

Tags: c#

I'm working on a C# winForm that uses a dataGridView that has a Column with multiple DataGridViewCell types. e.g.

```
DataGridView dvg = new DataGridView();
dgv.Columns.Add("colCtrl", "Ctrl");

DataGridViewComboBoxCell cboCell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();

TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
txtBox.Name = "MyTextBox";
txtBox.KeyDown += txtBox_KeyDown;

cboCell.Items.Add(txtBox);

DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
row.Cells.Add(cboCell);

dgv.Rows.Add(row);

private void txtBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   DataGridViewComboBoxCell cb = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)     ((TextBox)sender).Parent;
   TextBox txtBox = (TextBox)sender;

   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
   {
       if (!cb.Items.Contains(txtBox.Text))
           cb.Items.Add(txtBox.Text);
   }
}
```

the textBox control is not being render to the comboBox Items collection. Its seems to be added when I step through code but It's not showing up. I'd basically like to use the textBox to add string items to the my comboBox dropDownList. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance,
-DA

Answer (score 0):

Items in ComboBox are strings in default. In WPF, you can just add the controls to the ComboBox. In Winforms, you might need to customize your comboBox.

Comment: been up all night searching for an answer. i can't believe MSDN doesn't even have any examples on this issue or even how to go about it as far as inheritance. this is stupid! i'm almost at the point of giving up!

Answer (score 0):

Trying to render different control types in a DataGridView is hard. DataGridView  is meant to display data not so much control it.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx):
DataGridView: **Displays** data in a customizable grid.

I suggest you use the [DataRepeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488279%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) control if your version of C# has it

Comment: this is ridiculous! i can't believe how convoluted and incomplete the dataGridView API is! MSFT needs to go back to the drawing board! so in other words I can't added controls to the dataGridViewComboBoxCell dropDownList lol? it seems like everytime i need to work with the dataGridView i have to jump through hoops to get anything done!

Comment: I'm not saying you can't I'm just saying that you should probably check out datarepeater

Answer (score 0):

All I have to say is MSFT needs go back to the drawing board and revamp the dataGridView. Don't get me wrong it has a lot good functionality but its WAY to convoluted and lacks common features that you would expect the API to support! Seems like every time I work with the dataGridView I have to jump through hoops to accomplish the most simple of task, but anyway here's my hack job to render a textbox...keep in mind this is a HACK far from being the correct way to do this, oh well... hope this helps someone.

```
    public class DropDownCellWithTextBox : DataGridViewComboBoxCell
    {
       ContextMenuStrip dropDownList;
       ToolStripTextBox txtBox;
       DataGridView dgv;

       public DropDownCellWithTextBox(DataGridView _dgv)
       {
           dgv = _dgv;

           dropDownList = new ContextMenuStrip();

           txtBox = new ToolStripTextBox();
           txtBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
           txtBox.KeyDown += txtBox_KeyDown;

           dropDownList.Items.Add(txtBox);
       }

   public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex,
   object initialFormattedVaulue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
   {
       base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex,initialFormattedValue,dataGridViewCellStyle);

            ContextMenuStrip cms = DataGridView.EditingControl as ContextMenuStrip;
   }

    protected override void OnMouseClick(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //base.OnMouseClick(e)
        dropDownList.Size = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Size;
        dropDownList.Show(dgv.PointToScreen(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
    }

    private void txtBx_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        ToolStripTextBox txt = (ToolStripTextBox)sender;
        if (txt.Text == "")
            return;

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            ToolStripMenuItem tsmi = new ToolStripMenuItem(txt.Text);
            tsmi.Name = txt.Text;

            if (!dropDownList.Items.ContainsKey(tsmi.Name))
            {
                 dropDownList.Items.Add(tsmi);
                 txt.Text = "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```